# ¿Como ajusto el ancho de un modal al contenido del mismo?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tengo un modal en el cual indico información preliminar para realizar dichas acciones, pero algunos datos superan el espacio del `modal`. Aca un ejemplo de un `modal` que uso.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="ModalEliminar" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll; display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content"> 
               <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-tittle">Eliminar </h4>                </div> 
               <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="eliminar_id" disabled="" value="4">
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              ¿Esta seguro de eliminar este item?
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Código: </label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_codigo">10000</span>
                              </div> 
                         </div> 
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Nombre: </label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_nombre">Miovit producto que requiere cuidado y esterilización antes de entrar al proceso</span>
                              </div>
                         </div> 
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Presentación: </label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_presentacion">Jarabe<br>155 gg</span>
                              </div> 
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Área Productiva:</label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_linea_de_produccion">ASDF6546546546SADF541652SDF1651654165SDFSADF4641452451</span>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
 <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>  
 <span class="hidden-xs"> Cerrar</span> 
</button>                          <button type="button" id="Eliminar" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> 
 <span class="hidden-xs"> Eliminar</span> 
</button>                    </div>
               </form>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Si se que hay otros `modals` como el `lg` y el normal. Pero abarcan mucho mas de lo que yo necesito, o si utilizara el `lg` el se adaptara al contenido, es el objetivo de mi pregunta.

NOTA: si se que no hay un código tan exageradamente largo pero pueden haber otros textos X en mi web q pueden superar la cantidad de espacio que hay en el modal.

PD: darle a "pantalla completa" para observar el modal como funciona en mi sistema.

De antemano gracias al que pueda ayudarme.

Comment: En esta linea usa modal-resize como puedes ver
div class="modal-dialog **modal-resize**"
y se adaptara a tu medida.
Saludos

Comment: Como comenta Fernando Forcen
con un "modal-lg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución sería añadirle la propiedad `float:left;` al selector `.modal-content`.

(revisa el snippet siguiente a página completa)

```js
jQuery('#ModalEliminar').on('shown.bs.modal',function() {
   var anchoCSS = 300,
       anchoEfectivo = jQuery(this).find('.modal-content').outerWidth(),
       margenIzquierdo=(300-anchoEfectivo)/2;
       
   jQuery(this).find('.modal-content').css('margin-left',margenIzquierdo);
   
});
```

```css
.modal-content {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminar" >Open modal</button>
 

<div class="modal fade" id="ModalEliminar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content"> 
               <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-tittle">Eliminar </h4>                </div> 
               <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="eliminar_id" disabled="" value="4">
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              ¿Esta seguro de eliminar este item?
                         </div>
                         
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Área Productiva:</label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_linea_de_produccion">ASDF6546546546SADF541652SDF1651654165SDFSADF4641452451</span>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
 <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>  
 <span  > Cerrar</span> 
</button>                          <button type="button" id="Eliminar" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> 
 <span > Eliminar</span> 
</button>                    </div>
               </form>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Notarás que el modal queda des-centrado, porque `modal-sm` tiene un ancho de 300px en duro en la hoja de estilos. La única manera de compensar esto que se me ocurre sería usando JS para obtener el ancho efectivo, restarle 300px y darle al modal un `margin-left` equivalente a la mitad de esa diferencia.

Pero todo depende de cómo abras tu modal. Si no usas JS sino sólo html para ello, ya se vuelve más complicado.

EDIT: Ahí dejé el snipper con la lógica para compensar el nuevo ancho modificando el margin-left. Pof favor ver el snippet en pantalla completa.

Comment: yo utilizo js para abrir el modal

Comment: Te dejé el snippet con el cambio para el margen.

Comment: gracias hermano

Answer (score 3):

Yo creo que cambiandolo a `modal-lg`es justo lo que buscas. Te he puesto el resultado con el ejemplo que has puesto.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="ModalEliminar" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll; display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content"> 
               <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-tittle">Eliminar </h4>                </div> 
               <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="eliminar_id" disabled="" value="4">
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              ¿Esta seguro de eliminar este item?
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Código: </label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_codigo">10000</span>
                              </div> 
                         </div> 
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Nombre: </label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_nombre">Miovit producto que requiere cuidado y esterilización antes de entrar al proceso</span>
                              </div>
                         </div> 
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Presentación: </label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_presentacion">Jarabe<br>155 gg</span>
                              </div> 
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Área Productiva:</label>
                              <div>
                                   <span id="eliminar_linea_de_produccion">ASDF6546546546SADF541652SDF1651654165SDFSADF4641452451</span>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
 <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>  
 <span class="hidden-xs"> Cerrar</span> 
</button>                          <button type="button" id="Eliminar" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> 
 <span class="hidden-xs"> Eliminar</span> 
</button>                    </div>
               </form>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

En tu caso en particular el problema que tienes es que la cadena de texto del span `#eliminar_linea_de_produccion` no tiene espacios y por defecto no se ajusta su anchura a la disponible, lo que hace que esta sobresalga del dialogo.

Si lo que quieres es mantener el dialogo con el tamaño estrecho, para este caso en particular puedes hacer que el texto se adapte al ancho disponible utilizando la opción de css `word-wrap` que partirá las lineas que excedan del ancho aunque no tengan espacios:

```
#eliminar_linea_de_produccion {
  word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

Otra opción puede ser que aparezca una barra de desplazamiento cuando el texto sobresalga modificando el css del contenedor del span 
`#eliminar_linea_de_produccion`:

```
div #padre_de_eliminar_linea_de_produccion {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```